# converting SQL spatial data into spatialite format

Tags: android, sql-server, android-sqlite, spatialite

I am developing an offline Digital Addressing System. I need to keep spatial data in my spatialite. However, i have my spatial data in SQL server. How do i convert them into a format that can be used by the spatialite?

Answer (score 0):

SpatiaLite supports DBF format for import and/or export.  Also you can export your data from sql server as a CSV file and then import it to your DBF.